# Django Admin Columnise StackedInline

Tags: django, templates

I would like to have a stacked inline container and a normal container positioned next to each other for a specific model in my admin.

Is there anyway I can do this with the built in functionality or a plugin in Django 1.8 ? Or is the only option to create a custom admin template ? (Which I would like to avoid)

Comment: are you looking for `NestedInline`? [django-nested-admin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nested-admin)? There are also a [#9025](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025) where the community is looking forward to have this internally

Comment: It certainly looks interesting, but from what I have seen it nests them, leading to a longer list. What I want to achieve is safe space and put two stackedinlines next to each other, with a simple css float:left...